# GDB MI Interface parser

Tags: qt, gdb

I am trying to write a GDB frontend. I use GDB for debugging embedded targets, especially with ARM processors. I have used Eclipse before, but I didn't like it very much. At work, we use Lauterbach Trace32, which is one of the most comfortable debuggers I have ever used. That's why I started a project where I try to implement a very similar application as a GDB frontend, which is specialised to embedded debugging.

However, I already have implemented some very basic commands, like viewing the source code, viewing registers of the target etc., which works well. Currently, I am implementing breakpoints. But for this I need some help.

I use Qt (with Qtcreator) on Linux for my project, so I have set up a QProcess for the gdb running in the background. I use the GDB Mi2 interface to communicate with gdb. Then, using write() I can send commands and with a SIGNAL, I can receive the responses from GDB. This works well, but the answers from GDB in this MI format are very ugly to parse. Could anyone give me a hint how this can be done in a elegant way? I tried BOOST to build a parser, which worked, but this is a much too complicated way in my opinion. Is there some better way to parse the GDB responses?

Comment: Although this thread is now over a year old, I would like you to know that Lauterbach TRACE32 (which you've rated as comfortable debugger) can also be used as a GDB frontend. However it is not for free of course.

Answer (score 1):

There's no truly great way to parse MI.  MI is quite old and so predates the widespread adoption of XML and JSON.  Also, even more unfortunately for you, there are a few known MI emission bugs in gdb (search bugzilla and the list archives) -- spots where gdb's MI output doesn't conform to the MI grammar.  These have gone unfixed because it was judged that changing the output (without bumping the MI version number, something nobody seems to want to drive) would break existing parsers without much corresponding benefit.

The good news is that there are a few reusable parsers already in existence.  So I would suggest using one of those.  The parser in `nemiver` is written in C++ and is a reusable library.  However as you're already using Qt you might check out the parsers in Qt Creator or KDevelop.

It might also be possible to roll your own gdb interface by programming gdb in Python.  However, there are likely to be some holes in gdb's Python API, so I would only recommend it if you also want to get into hacking on the gdb Python layer as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked ad nemiver, but it looks very complicated. I also took a look at http://gede.acidron.com/, whose source code is much easier. The class Com implements the communication with gdb, but it is also a bit complicated, it would be nice if you could help me understand it. I have now managed to include this single class in my program, and I can even send commands to gdb, but receiving the answers seems like a more complicated task with this class.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about it.  I don't even remember hearing about that GUI before :)  Another option of course is to take an existing GUI like that one and modify it to work the way you want.  Then you may not have to deal with gdb and MI much at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is the pygdbmi python library for exactly this purpose (it did not exist when you originally asked your question) https://github.com/cs01/pygdbmi

gdbgui is a frontend that utilizes pygdbmi: https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui

Have fun!

Disclaimer: I am the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator itself has a parser for (some superset of) the MI protocol, see plugins/debugger/debuggerprotocol.{h,cpp} in its sources. This (superset) protocol also used to capture data from Qt Creator's "pretty printing" produces and also serves as the debugger->frontend channel for the LLDB integration.

The protocol implementation is fairly well separated from the rest of Qt Creator's debugger plugin. It should be re-usable.